# Transformar función de jQuery a Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Estoy usando el siguiente código ([obtenido de la página web de SrPago](https://devcenter.srpago.com/en/docs/library/tokenization/javascript-tokenization/)):

```
var onSuccessHandler = function(result){
    $("#response_message").html("Con este token procesará el pago desde su Servidor " + result.token);
    $("#tokenInput").val(result.token);
    $("#card-payment-form").submit();
};

var onFailHandler = function(error){
    $("#response_message").html("Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
};

SrPago.token.create(onSuccessHandler,onFailHandler);
```

Ese código utiliza jQuery, pero yo estoy usando Angular 2. Quisiera saber cómo puedo pasar esas funciones jQuery a Angular ya que he intentado de diferentes formas y no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para dejar de usar jQuery en el código especificado, sólo necesitas unos pocos retoques:

- Cambia `$(...)` por `document.querySelector(...)` para los selectores de elemento (nota que esto funciona porque se selecciona un único valor, si fueran varios sería `querySelectorAll`)
- Cambia `.html(...)` por `.innerHTML = ...`. El método `.html()` de jQuery pone el parámetro como contenido HTML en el elemento. En JavaScript puro puedes utilizar `.innerHTML` para eso.
- Cambia `.val(...)` por `.value = ...`. El método `.val()` de jQuery le da el valor especificado al campo del formulario. En JavaScript puro puedes pasar ese valor al atributo `value`.

Aplicando esos cambios, el código de la pregunta quedaría así sin jQuery:

```
var onSuccessHandler = function(result){
    document.querySelector("#response_message").innerHTML = "Con este token procesará el pago desde su Servidor " + result.token;
    document.querySelector("#tokenInput").value = result.token;
    document.querySelector("#card-payment-form").submit();
};

var onFailHandler = function(error){
    document.querySelector("#response_message").innerHTML = "Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message;
};

SrPago.token.create(onSuccessHandler,onFailHandler);
```

No relacionado: fíjate que en el ejemplo del sitio web, el método `SrPago.token.create()` tiene 3 parámetros, pero en tu código sólo lo estás llamando con 2 (que no coinciden en orden).